# How to create custom widget in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm completely new to Android programming, so I'm not really sure what I should be searching for. I have a LinearLayout element on one of my activities.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/comment_area"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

I have a JSON array of comments (userName, commentText, commentDate) that I want to add into this LinearLayout though a loop. I created a comment_view.xml layout and created a CommentWidget class extending LinearLayout. Frankly I have no idea if this is the correct approach, and I don't think it is because I can't get the comments to load in.

My class is

```
public class CommentWidget extends LinearLayout {
    private String text;

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public CommentWidget(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public CommentWidget(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate(){
        super.onFinishInflate();
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

My widget layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.myproject.CommentWidget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/comment_text"/>


</com.myproject.CommentWidget>
```

Inside my loop on the activity I was calling:

```
    CommentWidget w = new CommentWidget(this);
    w.setText(comment.getText());
    mtxtArea.addView(w);
```

But nothing shows up. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm correctly receiving the JSON into an array already.

**Update: Answer**
Windsurfer's answer below set me on the right track to use a ListView for what I am trying to accomplish. Using his links and some searching I found out that extending the ArrayAdapter is the most appropriate for JSON type data. I ended up following the tutorial at the following link

https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well extend the LinearLayout to do this, but Android already has a couple of widgets designed for this. I believe you're looking for a ListView to display an array of data. Rather than creating a new widget, take a look at how a ListView works. A ListView uses an adapter to bind data to it. You will still have to design the layout for a single comment item, but a lot of the heavy lifting is done by the ListView and it's adapter.

Here are some links to get you started:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Take a look at [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) by Romain Guy who introduces ListViews too.